# How can i calculate phrase in pause prediction

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, phrase

I have an assignment to calculate the same phrases in two text to calculate the accuracy of pause prediction system.

For example :
- the origin sentence : I/1 have breakfast/1 before/1 going to/1 school.
- the sentence from pause prediction system : I/1 have/1 breakfast/1 before/1 going/1 to/1 school.

The output that I have to get:
    - relevant_picked_up_phrase : 3
    - relevant_not_picked_up_phrase : 2
    - not_relevant : 4

The explanation on how to get the output number :
-    for relevant_picked_up_phrase : check and count the same phrases between 2 sentences ( I , before, school = 3 )
-    for relevant_not_picked_up_phrase : check and count the different phrases between 2 sentences in the origin sentence ( have breakfast, going to = 2)
-    for not_relevant : check and count the different phrases between 2 sentences in the sentence from pause prediction system ( have, breakfast, going, to = 4)

How can we code in python to calculate the phrases to get that output? I have tried, but cannot find the exact calculation.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this approach so far:

```
from multiset import Multiset

original = 'I/1 have breakfast/1 before/1 going to/1 school.'
prediction = 'I/1 have/1 breakfast/1 before/1 going/1 to/1 school.'

original_counts = Multiset(original.split('/1'))
prediction_counts = Multiset(prediction.split('/1'))

print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', (original_counts & prediction_counts))
print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', (original_counts - prediction_counts))
print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', (prediction_counts - original_counts))
print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', len(original_counts & prediction_counts))
print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', len(original_counts - prediction_counts))
print('relevant_picked_up_phrase: ', len(prediction_counts - original_counts))
```

You might need to install `multiset` with `$ pip install multiset`